# Creating http response as a return value for mockito

Tags: java, rest, junit, mockito, httpresponse

I am new to Mockito testing and am testing a GET request.

I have mocked the call but now I need to return `HttpResponse<Cars[]>` because these values are later used in for loop.

How can I create a dummy `HttpResponse` where the body contains the array of `Car` objects.

The method where Get request is used in class `CarProvider` is:

```
public HttpResponse<Cars[]> getCars(String carId, String carname) {
    return Unirest.get(endpointUrl)
          .header("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .queryString("carId",cardId)
          .queryString("carname",carname)
          .asObject(Cars[].class);
}
```

This is used in another class `CarsUsers` in below method:

```
public List<Cars> getCars(String carId, String carname) {
  HttpResponse<Cars[]> response = carProvider.getCars(carId, carname);
  for(Cars car: response.getBody){
     //use car and do something
}
```

My test method is as follows:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Mock
    HttpResponse<Cars[]> httpresponse;
    @Mock
    CarsProvider carsProvider;

    @Mock
    CarsUser carsUser;

    @Test
    public void getCarsTest(){
     Mockito.when(carsUser.getCars(Matchers.anyString(), 
     Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(getDummyCarsList());

     Mockito.when(carsProvider.getCars(Matchers.anyString(), 
     Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(httpResponse);

     }

    private List<Cars> getDummyCarsList(){
    //create a dummy list of cars
    }
}
```

I get `NullPointerException` pointing to `for(Cars car: response.getBody){}`.

I am assuming that body doesnt have any value and hence the exception is thrown.

Appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe show the method you're trying to test

Comment: Can you update your question to show us some sample code? The answer to your question is likely to be something like this: `HttpResponse response = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class); Mockito.when(response.xxx).thenReturn(arrayOfCars);` but without more detail from you it's hard to say exactly what you should do. Please consider posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sample code might be really helpful

Comment: have updated the question

Comment: prepare your mock with an appropriate body, which may itself be a mock: `when(response.getBody()).thenReturn(something)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you really need `CarProvider` to return a `HttpResponse<Car[]>`?

It feels like an aspect of the underlying comms (`HttpResponse`) might be leaking here. If the purpose of the `CarProvider` is to *provide cars* then perhaps it should be typed accordingly.

So, if you declared `CarProvider` as follows ...

```
public class CarProvider {
    // should perhaps consider List<Car> instead of Car[] here ...
    public Cars[] getCars(String carId, String carname) {
        HttpResponse<Car{}> response = Unirest.get(endpointUrl)
          .header("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .queryString("carId",cardId)
          .queryString("carname",carname);

        return deserialise(response.getBody());
    }

    private Car[] deserialise(ResponseBody body) {
        // read the body and deserialise to Car[] 
    }
}
```

... then your test method would simplify to:

```
@Test
public void getCarsTest(){
    Mockito.when(carsUser.getCars(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(getDummyCarsList());

    // ...
}

private Cars[] getDummyCarsList(){
    return new Car{} {new Car(...), new Car(...)};
}
```

However, if this really is not possible and you really *must* mock `HttpResponse<Car[]>` then that'll look something like this:

```
HttpResponse<Car[]> mockedResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
Mockito.when(mockedResponse.getCode()).thenReturn(200);
Mockito.when(mockedResponse.getBody()).thenReturn(someSerialisedFormOfYourCarArray);

Mockito.when(carsUser.getCars(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(mockedResponse);
```

Comment: Thank you for response i will try this

Comment: FWIW, I've just updated the answer to show you how to mock the `HttpResponse` in case you really cannot redeclare `CarProvider`.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me realize that i need to mock even the array of Cars